# Difference between List.subList and slice in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, slice

I recently realised there are two very similar functions in Kotlin for getting a portion of a `List`, but I'm unsure of the difference:

The [documentation for `List.subList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html) says:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex (inclusive) and toIndex (exclusive). The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>
> Structural changes in the base list make the behavior of the view undefined.

whereas the [documentation for `slice`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/slice.html) says:

> Returns a list containing elements at indices in the specified indices range.

Or

> Returns a list containing elements at specified indices.

It seems that the key differences are that the first one returns a "*view of the portion*" of the list, and whether non-structural changes are reflected? However I'm not quite sure what this means.

I looked at the source code for the `slice` function:

```
public fun <T> List<T>.slice(indices: IntRange): List<T> {
    if (indices.isEmpty()) return listOf()
    return this.subList(indices.start, indices.endInclusive + 1).toList()
}
```

But it returns a list from the `subList` function.

Could someone explain the differences between these two functions and when you might want to use one over the other?

Comment: You can checkout example in which mentions the difference between `sublist` and `slice`, also alternatively `drop` and `take` functionality to achieve the same https://chetangupta.net/bbk7/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The key in `List<T>.slice` function is the `.toList()` at the end, which will create a new **List** with the elements, using a shallow element copy.

For summary:

- `.slice()` will create a new **List** with the shallow copy of the subset of elements; if the original list contains objects, changes to values within the objects will be seen in the slice, but the replacement of an object or scalar in the original list will not be seen in the slice
- `.subList()` is only a view of the original **List**, which will reflect changes to both the objects/scalars in the list as well as changes to the values within the objects in the list

You can see differences here: https://pl.kotl.in/-JU8BDNZN

```
fun main() {
    val myList = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val subList = myList.subList(1, 3)
    val sliceList = myList.slice(1..2)
    println(subList) // [2, 3]
    println(sliceList) // [2, 3]
    
    myList[1] = 5
    println(subList) // [5, 3]
    println(sliceList) // [2, 3]
}
```

Comment: You should be aware, that the list content does not get copied when using slice, but also references the same object. So if you make changes to an object in myList, the changes will also affect the object in sliceList, since it's the same object. You can checkout this sample here https://pl.kotl.in/AFbm6dWXf